# NodeJs talks to ubuntu server on EC2

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Recently I have installed a nodejs app on my EC2 directory, listening to one of the port from EC2 instance. I also have a couple of executable python scripts on my EC2 ubuntu Linux server.

The way I run those executable python script is to use putty and connect to ubuntu via command line( for windows, Sure for Mac I use terminal). I am just wondering, is it possible to have the nodejs app does the same job, so I will have a UI based on the web app, which can talk to ubuntu and execute those scripts (python scripts such as "python run.py".

Please advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the Python scripts are on the same server as the Node app, and you'd like to run them from Node.js

```
var execScript = require('child_process').execFile;
execScript('/path/to/python/script.py');
```

Should probably do the trick.

Can also add options or callbacks as needed, see the docs here: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html